# Locate to specific bound by using fitBounds of react-mapbox-gl

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, react-map-gl

I want to make the map to relocate to constant bound by button click event.
When page is loaded, it shows the bound that I get the bound that I calculated correctly.
After loading, I need to navigate to the markers that I drew.
After navigating to several markers, need to fly to original bound that I got first.
But it is locating to London city.
I am not sure why it is not relocating to original bound.

Here is my code

```
<CustomMapbox
    showAll={this.state.showAll}
    center={this.state.center}
    fitBounds={this.state.bound}
    zoom={[8]}
    containerStyle={{
       height: "100%"
    }} onClick={this.onClickMap}
>
     <Marker
        locations={this.state.places}
        data={this.state.product}
        onClick={this.onClickPosition} 
     />

      { (this.state.selectedPoint ) && (this.state.showPopup) &&
         <Popup key={`${this.state.selectedPoint[0]}_${this.state.selectedPoint[1]}`} coordinates={this.state.selectedPoint}>
              <StyledPopup>
                <div>{this.state.selectedUPCDate}</div>
              </StyledPopup>
         </Popup>
                }
</CustomMapbox>
```

As you can see my code I am using `CustomMapbox` component and props such as `showAll`, `center`, `fitBounds` for Map.
`showAll` is to show all of the markers or not.
When `showAll` is true, need to show all of the markers so is needed to be shown the area with `fitBound`.
And when `showAll` is false, it is needed to be shown the center point.

I made the `CustomMapbox` to select the correct props by `showAll` variable.
In `CustomMapbox`, if `showAll` is true, `center` props would be removed and or not, `fitBounds` props would be removed.
Problem is to be shown correctly this area when page is loaded but not showing after doing the navigate to specific center.

Are there any solution to make this function with `react-mapbox-gl`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

everyone!
I solved it myself.
When using the fitBounds, need to use the center of that bound.
It is working perfectly now

Don't need to use the `showAll` flag for `fitBounds`
Just needed to use the `fitBounds` and its `center` value

Comment: It will be great if you could post the updated code